# Apply CSS Styling to data tables child tr's

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to set the height of the tr's in my jQuery Data table rows.

Here is what i have in my CSS.

```
#TableWrapper tbody tr {
    min-height: 35px; 
}
```

Below is a screen shot from console of my table, as you can see the id="TableWrapper".

[image]

Could someone say what i'm doing wrong to style these child tr's ?

Comment: Click on one of those `tr`s in the dev tools and see if you can see your style. If it has a strikethrough, it means something with higher precedence is overriding your style.

Comment: May be you should apply it for `#TableWrapper tbody tr td` instead of `tr`

Comment: @mattytommo There is not strikethrough.

Comment: @AkhilSekharan Changed to that and had no effect.

Comment: @Pomster Then how about `#TableWrapper tbody tr td > *`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-max-height)

> In CSS 2.1, the effect of 'min-height' and 'max-height' on tables, inline tables, table cells, table rows, and row groups is undefined.

So you can try with height property.

```
#TableWrapper tbody tr
{
  height: 35px; 
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/S6gvt/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
#TableWrapper tbody tr 
{
    height: 35px;
    float: left; 
}
```

Try the above style.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
#TableWrapper tbody tr td{
    min-height: 35px; 
}
```

JsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/MLJMP/

Answer (score -1):

If you have got the right element, and you write it's CSS and if it does not appear as it should, chances are that Your css is being overridden by some other CSS.

Moreover you can use "!important" in your CSS to make it important and avoid overrides.

```
#TableWrapper tbody tr {
    min-height: 35px !important; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks i will remember this in the future, but it has not fixed my problem.

Comment: your problem can not be solved by us unless we have complete CSS/ or atleast how it is rendered.

Comment: you could use FireFox's firebug plugin and get us the CSS applied to your element.